# QClipboard cannot get clipboard data if copied from Notepad/Chrome

Tags: c++, qt, windows-8.1, clipboard

In my program, my users can copy a string of text from anywhere and paste it into my program. I use the simple `QApplication::clipboard()->text();` function and everything works as expected. However, several of my users are having problems when trying to copy and paste on Windows 8.1

Here is how I access the clipboard text from my paste function:

```
QString clipboard = QApplication::clipboard()->text();

//check if the clipboard is empty
if(QApplication::clipboard()->text().isEmpty())
    return;

//do something with clipboard
```

But if the text was copied from Notepad or Chrome, the text is ALWAYS empty. Windows 7 users have not had any problems. Not ALL Windows 8 users have this issue, it's only a handful but the issue it consistent. When copied from some other random places or within my program itself, the clipboard works fine.

I've tried using `mimeData`. When using the function `formats()`, only plain text is an available format, but the text is always empty.

The text being copied from Notepad/Chrome shows up fine in clipboard viewers and stuff and can be pasted elsewhere in other programs.

Copying and pasting is a very important feature in my program and its frustrating that my users can't copy and paste from Notepad or Chrome.

Any ideas? Thanks for your time. :)

EDIT: I tried using the "windows" style technique. There was no change. Here is my current, still unworking code:

```
QString clipboard = QApplication::clipboard()->text();

//check if the clipboard is empty
if(clipboard.isEmpty())
{
    //might not actually be empty. Check using the other technique
    if (IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_TEXT) && OpenClipboard(NULL))
        {
            HGLOBAL hGlobal = GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT) ;//hGlobal is NULL
            if (hGlobal != NULL)//This never gets called because it is NULL
            {
                LPTSTR lpszData = (LPTSTR) GlobalLock(hGlobal) ;
                if (lpszData != NULL)
                {
                    clipboard.fromLocal8Bit((const char *)lpszData);
                    GlobalUnlock(hGlobal) ;
                }
            }
            CloseClipboard() ;
        }

    if(clipboard.isEmpty())
        return;
}
```

The copied text shows up fine in a clipboard viewer, but my program can't get to it no matter what:
[image]

How come GetClipboardData() isn't picking anything up? Again, the copied text CAN be pasted in any other program I've tried... just not mine. But if copied from somewhere else, it works no problem.

Comment: first eliminate the possibility that windows 8.1 is restricting access to the clipboard. Copy from the problematic source to another program.

Comment: Sure. I just wanted to include that the only users that have had this issue had Windows 8.1 and I've never heard about it happen on any other OS. I'm not sure of it's significance, but I thought I would include it anyway.

Comment: "The text being copied from Notepad/Chrome shows up fine in clipboard viewers and stuff and can be pasted elsewhere in other programs."

Comment: didn't read that line sorry :|

Comment: Have you tried allocating your hglobal variable first? Like this: HGLOBAL hGlob = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, 64);
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/80db3kax.aspx

Comment: Just to check, did you try to disable any antivirus or antimalware tool on this machines ? maybe something is blocking your app from acessing clipboard.

Comment: Yeah I told him to disable it. Either way, the tool can access the clipboard, just not if it was copied from certain locations. Tbh, I find this really puzzling how no one has any idea what's going on...

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: With this version, When the user copies text and text gets to clipboard, a function copies the text this time to an internal text file not directly to your program, using `QFile`. Another function copies the text from the internal text file to your program. By this way, i think your program wouldn't have to directly deal with text in the clipboard

clipboard.h

```
#ifndef CLIPBOARD_H
#define CLIPBOARD_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QClipboard>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>

class ClipBoard : public QDialog {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ClipBoard(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~ClipBoard();

private slots:
    //the functions that will copy and paste text from the text file
    void copyToTextFile();
    void paste();

private:

    QPushButton *button;
    QTextEdit *edit;
    QString textFromClipBoard;
    QClipboard *clipBoardText;

    QString clipboard;

};

#endif // CLIPBOARD_H
```

clipboard.cpp

```
#include "clipboard.h"
#include "ui_clipboard.h"

ClipBoard::ClipBoard(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent) {

    button = new QPushButton("&Paste Copied Text");

    edit = new QTextEdit;

    /*when user copies text and text gets to clipboard, the text is copied 
      from clipboard to a text file then copied from the text file to the   
      program*/
    connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(copyToNotepad()));
    connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(paste()));


    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(button);
    layout->addWidget(edit);


    setLayout(layout);

}

/*This function copies text from the clipboard to an internal text file 
  created by the program*/
void ClipBoard::copyToTextFile() {
    clipboard = QApplication::clipboard()->text();

    QFile output("out.txt");
    if (output.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QFile::Truncate |   
    QIODevice::Text)) {
        QTextStream out(&output);
        out << clipboard;
    }
}

/*This function then copies the text from the internal text file and pastes 
  it to the text edit. So the program doesn't have to deal directly with the 
  clipboard*/
void ClipBoard::paste() {

    QFile input("out.txt");
    if (input.exists()) {
        if (input.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
            QTextStream in(&input);
            clipboard = in.readAll();
        }
    }

    edit->setText(clipboard);
}

ClipBoard::~ClipBoard() {

}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "clipboard.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    ClipBoard w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Look through and compare with your part of the code to see if there's something you did wrong. But as to how you claim it works on some Windows 8.1 systems and don't on others baffles me.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I use the same system, and I've varied it many times. This works on most machines, but a few of my users (which have paid for my program) cannot copy and paste from certain programs or sources. Is there any way to do it without using qt's library functions? Like a default windows way or something? maybe that would work

Comment: Include <windows.h> header in your code and use the winAPI method of getting clipboard data. Check this out  http://www.codeexperts.com/showthread.php?594-How-to-get-text-data-from-clipboard-using-WIN32

Comment: I just tried what you suggested. No change. Still things from Notepad cant be pasted but can from other programs. Check out my edit to see what I did.

Comment: Your edit works fine on my side. For all you may know, the problem might not really be from your program but their side. I think you need more info from those users like; "are they able to copy text from notepad and paste in other programs?",

Comment: I already said this twice. Read my post and comments. Yes they can.

Comment: OK sorry for that. But I still think the problem might not be from your program. Does your code do something with the copied text, like checking if some condition has been met before it is pasted ?

Comment: Yes it checks the first byte. But it is irrelevant because I've displayed a message box at every single step for this users version so I can pinpoint the problem. Only for those few users, is the clipboard empty. hGlobal never gets filled. I've done lots of "regular" bug testing and pinpointing. Not to mention that most of my users have no issues at all. GetClipboardData just cant get anything from the clipboard if it was copied from notepad. No clue why...

Comment: Try running your program in compatibility mode

Comment: Just had the user try it. No change.

Comment: @mc360pro try "clipboard.toUtf8()" to set the copied clipboard text to your application since it is capable of encoding all possible characters. Notepad normally uses ANSI encoding.

Comment: I don't see how that would make any change at all since clipboard = QApplication::clipboard()->text(); is just empty. The problem is not pasting, but getting the clipboard in the first place.

Comment: your program can't get text from the clipboard so i thought it would be convenient for the clipboard text to be available somewhere else also. So your program can have access to it. Have you applied my answer and it didn't work ?

Comment: Your answer makes no sense. If I could've filled the clipboard variable with text then I could've done anything I want with it. But my issue is that i cant get the clipboard at all.

Comment: You're telling my program to access the clipboard, so I can move it to a place where I can access it...... makes zero sense.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue,
the solution for me is sleep.

```
void MainWindow::on_clipboard_change(){

    QThread::msleep(1); //without this line I get allways empty clipboard

    QString text = QGuiApplication::clipboard()->text();

    qDebug() << "clipboard change event triggered ( " << text << " )";

}
```